# How to make worst case permutation of median of three quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I know time complexity of Quick sort. But I want to know how to create worst case permutation.

I guess there is a rule to make it. I thought it really much, but too difficult to me.

Please tell me how to create worst case for median of three quick sort, NOT JUST NORMAL QUICK SORT.
(for example, if pivot is most left side item in list, worst case permutation of list is sorted list, but how about pivot is median of three?)

[here is my quick sort algorithm code](https://gist.github.com/growingdever/2ab366f90c5ba8b17987)

Comment: If I can get some example about it, that will be really helpful to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "median of three quick sort"?  A quicksort with two pivots?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: "median of three" is a very well known method of selecting a pivot element during the partition step.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: A common implementation of quick sort (and introsort) uses the median of the first, middle, and last elements as the pivot, thus requiring less recursion in almost all cases.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks, @Blastfurnace and Mooing Duck!

Comment: You can derive this by induction, you get worst-case by showing it two maximal values at each partition, but lower values than previous ones at each partition. It will take an exact  knowledge of your quicksort's implementation. Most naive quicksorts can be worst-cased with an all-zero sequence.

Comment: Sorry. I need sequence that is not all elements are same.

Comment: @JuHongJung: (A) Why do you need the elements to not all be the same?  Can it be a single 1, and all the rest are zeros? (B) Since there's apperently additional requirements, edit them into the question, don't clarify in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really possible to create an arrangement of items that will cause all or even most Quicksort implementations to exhibit worst-case behavior. And in fact, depending on how the sort is implemented, a worst-case array on one run might be just fine on a subsequent run. That could happen if the implementation used a median-of-random-three to pick the pivot, and used a different seed each time the routine were called.

The C `qsort` function, and the sort library functions from many other libraries, are vulnerable to a "Quicksort killer" algorithm, though, that uses the information provided in the comparison callback to create a worst case scenario on the fly. It's surprisingly not difficult to do. See, for example, [A Killer Adversary for Quicksort](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf).

Comment: Musser in the [1997 paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.5196) that introduced Introsort claims it is possible to create such an arrangement of items. He calls them median-of-three killer sequences. Here's a Python list comprehension that generates such a sequence: `[i if i%2 == 1 else k+i-1 for i in range(1, k+1)] + [i for i in range(1, 2*k + 1) if i%2 == 0]`. Note that `k`should be set to an even value, and that the largest value in the sequence will be `2*k`.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no generic answer, because it depends on how the "median of three" part is implemented, and also how the "partition" step is implemented.  Many are easily put into the worst case by giving them a large number of elements that are all identical.  But for the more interesting case, the general concept is like this.

You start with numbers 1....N, and an "unknown array of the same size.  You don't know yet which numbers go in which index.

```
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
[ A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T]
```

The worst case for a quicksort is when the pivot picked is as close to one end as possible, so you want the biggest (or smallest) three elements in the three that will be considered for the median.  Usually, (but not always!) the first, middle, and last elements.

```
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
[19, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I,18, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S,20]
```

Now we know that after the partition step, the array will *probably* look like this, depending on how partition is implemented:

```
[ S, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I,18, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R,19,20]
                                                       ^ pivot
```

And then it will recurse on the [18-R] subsection.  (It may or may not additionally recurse on the [20] subsection, but there's nothing more we can do there.  And so we repeat the pattern, sticking the next two biggest elements in the end and middle of what's left:

```
[16, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,15,18, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q,17]
```

So after the partition it will look like:

```
[ P, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,15, Q, K, L, M, N, O,16,18,17]
                                               ^ pivot
```

Then we keep processing on the next subsection:

```
[ P, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,15, Q, K, L, M, N, O]
```

Note that as we are filling in the "biggest" elements, we're replacing the array locations (letters) with the numbers.  When we're done, we'll know which number goes in each array location.  Thus far I have this:

```
[19, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,15,18, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q,17,19,20]
```

Unfortunately, as I've mentioned, it depends quite a bit on how the pivot is picked and how the partition is implemented.  There probably exists a simple pattern you could fill in, but I haven't any idea what it would be.  You'll also notice I've been always placing the median of the top three on the far left, as that makes most partition implementations act more similar, but realistically, if you know how the partition works, it's probably better to put the median of the top three in one of the other two possible locations, just to give it one more swap to do.

Comment: Here is another idea: Let's say that the elements, compared to the pivot have to be smaller than the pivot, so we don't have any tolerance for duplicates in our implementation. If we have an array that only contains of the same objects, the pivot will always be that object. So the subarrays,  created by the quicksort will always have the length n-1, n-2,...,n-(n-1). The other subarray will always be empty. We now have the worst case for the number of comparisons: O(n^2), although we use the 3-median strategy. As I said, this is only possible if the implementation is vulnerable for duplicates.